# Swift Dijkstra Algorithm Error (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION)

Tags: swift, algorithm, dijkstra

So I've built a swift playground that uses Dijkstra's algorithm to find the shortest route. However, I can't seem to manipulate my txt file so that my function will work in every case. It only works for a select few pathways. Whenever I map out a pathway I believe should work, it responds with: `Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

How can I manipulate my txt file or my function/file manipulation to take my txt file input? (Where error occurred is marked -- near the bottom)

Usually the error occurs when trying to build a route backwards.
Ex: a1 to a3 works

Ex: a3 to a1 does not work

Code:

```
import Foundation

// Extensions

extension Array {
    func each<U>(closure:(Element)->U?)->U? {
        for i in self {
            let returnVal = closure(i)
            if (returnVal != nil) { return returnVal }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

extension Int {
    func times(closure:(Int)->Void) {
        for i in 0..<self { closure(i) }
    }
}

// Structs

struct Edge {
    var wt: Double
    var desV: Room
}

struct Graph { var vertices:[Room] }

// Room Class

class Room: Hashable {

    var name: String?
    var neighbors: [Edge] = []
    var hashValue: Int {
        get { return name!.hashValue }
    }

    init(){}

    convenience init(name:String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }

    func distanceToRoom(targetRoom:Room) -> Edge? {
        return self.neighbors.each({ (edge:Edge) -> Edge? in
            if (edge.desV == targetRoom) {
                return edge
            }
            return nil
        })
    }
}

// Functions

func == (lhs:Room, rhs:Room) -> Bool { return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue }

func say( a:String ) { print( a, terminator:"") }

func dijkstra(graph:Graph, target:Room) -> [Room:Room] {

    var queue = graph.vertices
    var distances:[Room:Double] = [:]
    var previousPaths:[Room:Room] = [:]
    let currentRoom:Room = queue[0]

    queue.each {(element:Room) -> Void? in
        distances[element] = Double.infinity
        previousPaths[element] = nil
        return nil
    }

    distances[currentRoom] = 0

    while (queue.count > 0) {

        var closestNode:Room? = nil
        let wt:Double = Double.infinity
        queue.each({ (Room:Room) -> Void? in
            if (closestNode == nil || wt < distances[Room]!) {
                closestNode = Room
            }
            return nil
        })
        if (closestNode! == target) {
            return previousPaths
        }

        let nodeIndex:Int? = queue.indexOf(closestNode!)
        queue.removeAtIndex(nodeIndex!)
        if (closestNode?.neighbors != nil && closestNode?.neighbors.count > 0) {
            closestNode?.neighbors.each({(neighbor:Edge) -> Void? in

                let wt = distances[closestNode!]! + closestNode!.distanceToRoom(neighbor.desV)!.wt
                if wt < distances[neighbor.desV] {
                    distances[neighbor.desV] = wt
                    previousPaths[neighbor.desV] = closestNode!
                }
                return nil
            })
        }
    }
    return previousPaths
}

// File Management

//let url = NSURL(string:"file:///Users/caleb/Documents/Xcode/CRHS/CRHS/dtb.txt")!
let url = NSURL(string: "file:///Users/caleb/Desktop/rooms.txt")!
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
let sdata = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let dataArray = sdata!.characters.split{$0 == "\n"}.map(String.init)
var rooms = [String:Room]()

print("data:\n-------")

for i in 0 ..< dataArray.count {
    let conn = dataArray[i].characters.split{$0 == "\t"}.map(String.init)
    var room1: Room
    if ( rooms[conn[0]] == nil ) {
        room1 = Room(name: conn[0])
    } else {
        room1 = rooms[conn[0]]!
    }

    let room2 = Room(name: conn[2])
    let edwt = (conn[1] as NSString).doubleValue
    var edge = Edge(wt: edwt, desV: room2)

    if room1.neighbors.count == 0 {
        room1.neighbors = [ edge ]
    } else {
        var found: Bool = false
        for e in room1.neighbors {
            if ( e.desV.name == edge.desV.name ) {
                found = true
            }
        }
        if ( found == false ) {
            room1.neighbors.append(edge)
        }
    }
    rooms[conn[0]] = room1
}

for (nam,room) in rooms {
    print(nam)
    print("----")
    for n in room.neighbors {
        if let un = n.desV.name {
            print( un, terminator: "  weight: ")
        }
        print( n.wt )
    }
    print("\n")
}
var namessofrooms = rooms.map { $0.0 }
var roomsofrooms = rooms.map { $0.1 }

print("Rooms:")
print(rooms)
print("-------\n")

// Calculating

var source = rooms["a1"]!
var target = rooms["a4"]!

roomsofrooms.append(source)
var reversedRooms: Array = roomsofrooms.reverse()
reversedRooms.append(target)

var graph = Graph(vertices: reversedRooms)
var paths = dijkstra(graph, target: target)
var pathVertices:[Room] = [target]

var child = target

while (child != source) {
    print(child.name)
    print(":::::")
    child = paths[child]! //Error occurs here
    print(child.name)
    pathVertices.append(child)
}

var pathString:[String] = pathVertices.reverse().map { (Room:Room) -> String in
    return Room.name!
}
print("solution:\n-------")
print(pathString)
```

Below is the file I input:

```
a1  1   a2
a2  1   a3
a3  1   a4
```

If I input the following file the code above will not work:

```
a1  1   a2
a2  1   a3
a3  1   a4
a4  1   a5
```

(Update: File Map Clarification)
First column is the first room, second is the weight between the rooms, third is the room connected to the first.

Comment: Because of the type and pointer safety inherent in Swift, crashes are usually due to some kind of overrun, like unbounded recursion or a data structure growing until it exceeds process limits. Use debugging statements for growable things like the length of your queue, and my money is on your detecting some unbounded growth.

Comment: Thanks. I'll comment if I find something going through my function.

Comment: I can't find where my queue is unbounded, it seems to only have a problem near the end when I go through the while loop or something else inside my Dijkstra function. It is limited to the amount of unique values in my first column of rooms. Tested for: (queue.count = 3 in the first file, queue.count = 4 in the second)